# migrating from data.task to folktale on handling rejection

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, folktale

In `data.task` package, I could resolve or reject a api call as following:

```
import Task from 'data.task';
import fs from 'fs';

const readFile = (filename, enc) => {
  return new Task((rej, res) =>
    fs.readFile(filename, enc, (err, contents) => {
      err ? rej(err) : res(contents);
    })
  );
};
```

How would I accomplish that in the new `folktale` version of `Task`? I can resolve requests, but how do I reject? I have tried the following:

```
const {task, rejected} = require('folktale/concurrency/task');
import fs from 'fs';

const readFile = (filename, enc) => {
  return task(res => {
    fs.readFile(filename, enc, (err, contents) => {
      err ? rejected(err) : res.resolve(contents);
    });
  });
};

const writeFile = (filename, contents) => {
  return task(res => {
    fs.writeFile(filename, contents, (err, success) => {
      err ? rejected(err) : res.resolve(success);
    });
  });
};

const app = readFile('FILE_DOESNOT_EXIST.json', 'utf-8')
  .map(contents => contents.replace(/8/g, '6'))
  .chain(contents => writeFile('config1.json', contents));

app.run().listen({
  onCancelled: () => {
    console.log('the task was cancelled');
  },
  onRejected: () => {
    console.log('something went wrong');
  },
  onResolved: value => {
    console.log(`The value is Good`);
  },
});
```

When I gave a file that doesn't exist, the onRejected handler does not get called.

**What do I expect to see:**
Since I have the program read a file that does not exist, it should run onRejected which should log `something went wrong`.

**What do I see now:**
Nothing. The program does not bug out, but it also does not produce anything, it simply runs as normal.

When using `data.task`(the older version of Task), I can use reject which is why it stills works there. How do I do it now with the new version of Task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok this is really silly! For some reason I could not find this solution right away on the doc.That's why I imported the `rejected` from `task`...

Basically `resolver` function coming from task has not only `resolve`, but also `reject`, which should have been obvious, but it was not on the doc.

So here is working code:

```
import {task} from 'folktale/concurrency/task';
import fs from 'fs';

const readFile = (filename, enc) => {
  return task(res => {
    fs.readFile(filename, enc, (err, contents) => {
      err ? res.reject() : res.resolve(contents);
    });
  });
};

const writeFile = (filename, contents) => {
  return task(res => {
    fs.writeFile(filename, contents, (err, success) => {
      err ? res.reject() : res.resolve(success);
    });
  });
};

const app = readFile('confg.json', 'utf-8')
  .map(contents => contents.replace(/8/g, '6'))
  .chain(contents => writeFile('config1.json', contents));

app.run().listen({
  onCancelled: () => {
    console.log('the task was cancelled');
  },
  onRejected: () => {
    console.log('something went wrong');
  },
  onResolved: value => {
    console.log(`The value is Good`);
  },
});
```